# SQL Server avoid repeating the collation type multiple times in a query

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have a query which selects rows from a source database (DatabaseA), and inserts them into a target database (Database B). The collation type differs between the databases and they cannot be changed. I need to address the collation difference in my query by explicitly specifying the collation for varchar fields.

Currently my query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseB.dbo.Users(
    Id,
    UserNumber,
    FirstName,
    Surname,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    AddressTown,
    AddressCity
)
SELECT 
    Id,
    UserNumber,
    FirstName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    Surname COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    Address1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    Address2 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    AddressTown COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    AddressCity COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS
FROM DatabaseA.dbo.Users
```

My question is, can I avoid typing the collation type for every string-based field? Is there a way that I can specify the collation type for the whole query at once? If this is not possible, are there any other shortcuts?